# Wallet Instant Buy in webview

Tags: ios, android-pay

My app will use Wallet Instant-Buy on Android. It's being used for physical goods. I'd like to use something similar on iOS.

Does anyone know if I can use the web-version of Wallet Instant Buy inside a UIWebView in my iOS app? Will cookies be persistent across app sessions? i.e. user won't need to sign-in repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use the Instant Buy web API from a webview either or iOS or Android. 
You should use a mWeb site for iOS users. 
The list of supported browsers are available at https://support.google.com/wallet/answer/2871041?hl=en